# PDF/A's Checkbox - iText 2.1.7

Tags: java, pdf, checkbox, itext, pdfa

I need to print a PDF/A document with my Java App, which implements iText 2.1.7. When I use a PDF Templates, my app works fine and print the checkbox checked if they satisfy the conditions.

But, when I use PDF/A Templates, my app doesn't fill these checkbox, but they receive the values correctly.

Can anyone help me? I dont know if this problem is in the template or in the code.

Comment: iText 1.2.7 must be ancient. I doubt you will find many people even remembering peculiarities of such a version.

Comment: I think the problem could be in the PDF/A template.

Comment: iText 1.2.7 does not even exist! We went from 1.2.4 on 15 March 2005 to 1.3.0 on 6 April 2005. https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases?after=1.4.1

Comment: Hahahaha, sorry, i wrote my itext version wrong, it's 2.1.7

Comment: 2.1.7 is from July 2009, I still consider that ancient. There has been done a lot of work on PDF/A since then.

Comment: @AngelVela I would propose you test the issue using a current iText version (using dedicated PDF/A classes for PDF/A file manipulation). If it still doesn't work, it would make sense to look closer at your template.

Comment: I cant use other iText version because our client uses other version and rarely approves frameworks changes.

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe in more detail what you are doing?

**thesis I:**
If you have a (non PDF/A) PDF with form fields and then you programmatically change a checkbox value with iText then the change is visible in the PDF (e.g. you can see it in adobe reader and on printed paper)
**Correct?**

**thesis II:** 
If you have a PDF/A compliant PDF and change the value of a checkbox then the change is not visible in the PDF (neither in adobe reader nor on printed paper)
**Correct?**

In the PDF format you need to differentiate between the appearance of a field and the (data) value of a field. Normally PDF/A documents are made for long term archiving and not to change values. If you still do that you need to ensure that you also update the appearance of a form field.

Try to update the appearance of the field you change (after you set the new value). You can do that with the following [method](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/javadoc/itext-2.1.7/com/lowagie/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#regenerateField(java.lang.String)):

```
AcroField fields;
boolean success = fields.regenerateField(String yourCheckboxFieldName);
```

Comment: I use a PDFA-1B Template created in Adobe Pro. Finally, I decided to use a TextBox with a X value as a CheckBox and its working. However I try in a free time your solution. Thanks!